# wrong result in date difference in android

Tags: java, android

I want to perform a date operation in my android app. What I want is to subtract two dates and get the result. But subtraction leads to the wrong result whenever I change the time zone to central daylight time.

I use the following code to find the difference between the two dates.

```
Long lDateDiff = dtCycleDay.getTime() - m_dtHistory[0].getTime();
lDateDiff = lDateDiff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
```

Here in `m_dtHistory[0]`, the date stored is `Thu Mar 01 00:00:00 CST 2012`.

And in my `dtCycleDay` variable the date changes from `Thu Mar 01 00:00:00 CST 2012`, `Thu Mar 02 00:00:00 CST 2012`, `Thu Mar 03 00:00:00 CST 2012`... and so on.

Now up to `Thu Mar 11 00:00:00 CST 2012`, the subtraction result is fine, but when the date changes to `Thu Mar 12 00:00:00 CDT 2012`, the `CST` changes to `CDT` and it show wrong subtraction result.

Why this happens and these happen only when I change the time zone to Central Daylight Time or pacific Daylight Time.

Comment: I know this question was answered a long time ago. If anyone faces this situation store your date in UTC and parse them at client-side application according to the local timezone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you mean by the "wrong" subtraction result?

My guess is that the result is 23 hours or 25 hours- which is exactly what I'd *expect* when a daylight transition occurs, as the intervening day *is* longer or shorter in terms of elapsed time. The "longer" day won't be relevant when dividing by 24, but the shorter one will... you're assuming that every day has 24 hours, and that you can therefore count the number of days by dividing the elapsed milliseconds by "the number of milliseconds in 24 hours". That doesn't work due to varying day lengths.

Don't forget that a `Date` value is *purely* an instant in time. It doesn't know about calendars or time zones... if  you want to know the difference in "local" dates and times (where midnight to midnight is always 24 hours), I'd suggest using [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) instead... `Date` and `Calendar` don't really do that for you.

If the real problem you're describing is the time zone changing at the wrong date, that's a different matter entirely, and could be due to various different causes. For one thing, you should show exactly which time zone you're talking about: the abbreviations are ambiguous, whereas the tzdb names (e.g. "Europe/Paris") aren't.

Comment: wrong subtraction result means..when i subtract Thu Mar 11 00:00:00 CST 2012 - Thu Mar 01 00:00:00 CST 2012. it will return 10. Similarly when i subtract Thu Mar 12 00:00:00 CDT 2012 - Thu Mar 01 00:00:00 CST 2012 it will return 10 instead of 11.

Comment: @Anshuman: Right - because instead of 264 hours, you've got 263 due to the DST transition.

Comment: But upto Thu Mar 11 00:00:00 CST 2012 it will give the perfect result only from Thu Mar 12 00:00:00 CDT 2012 it shows wrong result, is it becoz time zone changes to CDT.

Comment: @Anshuman: Yes, for exactly the reasons I've described in my answer. I suggest you reread my answer carefully. You *could* account for this by rounding, or you could use Joda Time and deal with `LocalDate` instead. (Joda Time is a far better date/time API.)

Comment: @Anshuman: Do you understand that on a day when the clocks go forward, the day only actually lasts 23 hours? That's the first, most important thing to understand. Once you've got that, everything else should follow.

Comment: Yeh i understand what u are saying but not able to config it out how to do it in my code

Comment: @Anshuman: To be honest, the *simplest* approach would be to divide by `(1000 * 60 * 60)` to get hours, then add a couple of hours, then divide by 24. That will work *if* you're expecting all your `Date` values to be midnight (which doesn't always even occur in a day, by the way, e.g. in Brazil). It's ugly though...

Comment: @Anshuman: As I say, just add a couple: if you've got 2 hours too many (which will be the normal case) then the result will be rounded down anyway. You could probably get away with only adding one, but if you add two it will cope if anyone adopts double daylight savings. (I would still thoroughly recommend moving to Joda Time when you get the chance though...)

Comment: ..yeh its working..one last question..is this code work for all time zone that provided in android device

Comment: @Anshuman: It should work for all time zones in terms of the date calculations - but when you're coming up with the `Date` values to start with, don't forget that Brazil and some other places move their clocks forward at midnight, so don't assume that midnight is the start of the day. There's also the "Samoa 2011" issue, where they skipped December 30th entirely. This code wouldn't handle that, but it's a real edge case.